# Convert an emoji to HTML UTF-8 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding

I have a rails server running, where I have a bunch of clocks emojis, and I want to render them to the HTML. The emojis are in ASCII format:

```
ch = "\xF0\x9F\x95\x8f" ; 12.times.map { ch.next!.dup }.rotate(-1)

# => ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

What I want is this:

```
> String.define_method(:to_html_utf8) { chars.map! { |x| "&#x#{x.dump[3..-2].delete('{}')};" }.join }

> ch = "\xF0\x9F\x95\x8f" ; 12.times.map { ch.next!.to_html_utf8 }.rotate(-1)
# => ["&#x1F55B;", "&#x1F550;", "&#x1F551;", "&#x1F552;", "&#x1F553;", "&#x1F554;", "&#x1F555;", "&#x1F556;", "&#x1F557;", "&#x1F558;", "&#x1F559;", "&#x1F55A;"]

> ?.to_html_utf8
# => "&#x1F584;"

> "".to_html_utf8
#=> "&#x1F42D;&#x1F439;"
```

As you can see the to_html_utf8 does use some brute force way to get the job done.
Is there a better way to convert the emojis in aforementioned html compatible UTF-8?

Please note that it would be better to avoid and rails helpers or rails stuff in general, and it can be run with ruby 2.7+ only using standard library stuff.

Comment: What do you mean by "The emojis are in ASCII format"? There are no emojis in ASCII.

Comment: I meant this: `?.b #=> "\xF0\x9F\x9A\x81"` or `?.force_encoding('ASCII') 
#=> "\xF0\x9F\x9A\x81"`. In other words, `\xF0\x9F\x9A\x81` instead of .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The emojis are in ASCII format:
>
> ```
> ch = "\xF0\x9F\x95\x8f"
> ```

`0xf0 0x9f 0x95 0x8f` is the character's UTF-8 *byte sequence*. Don't use that unless you absolutely have to. It's much easier to enter the emojis directly, e.g.:

```
ch = ''
#=> ""
```

or to use the character's *codepoint*, e.g.:

```
ch = "\u{1f550}"
#=> ""

ch = 0x1f550.chr('UTF-8')
#=> ""
```

You can usually just render that character into your HTML page if the "charset" is UTF-8.

If you want to turn the string's characters into their *numeric character reference* counterparts yourself, you could use:

```
ch.codepoints.map { |cp| format('&#x%x;', cp) }.join
#=> "&#x1f550;"
```

Note that the conversion is trivial – `1f550` is simply the character's (hex) codepoint.

Comment: Although this comment is unnecessary, but... Wow! Always get a very nice answer from you! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to simply use UTF-8 natively and not escaping anything.

Comment: Terrible problems with my font in the editor. There could be devs that may want to modify my program without GUI, in Vim, without the noto-fonts-emoji font. I don't think it's a good practice to write the emoji in the text editor. And also, it's always suggested to use & notation instead of dumping the emoji directly!